# Detekt. Disabled rules are still applying

Tags: android, kotlin, detekt

In my `detekt.yml` file I'm setting some rules to `false` for example

```
  LongMethod:
    active: false
    threshold: 60
```

but, when I run `./gradlew detekt`, the same rule is still showing up as an error.

Do I need to run another command so Detekt can see that this file changed?
Also, why in the Android Studio terminal do I have to run `./gradlew detekt` if I'm using Windows?? shouldn't it be `gradle detekt` instead?? I thought that `./gradlew` was for Mac/Linux but it doesn't work if I just type `gradle`

In my `gradle.properties` (project) I have the following:

```
plugins {
    id 'io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt' version "1.23.0" apply false
}
```

and in the app-level gradle file, I have this:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt'
}
```

Thank you!